# British Isles - Acceptable?

Tags: political-correctness, toponyms

Is the term *British Isles* still acceptable, or is it considered offensive to Irish people who may not consider their island legitimately connected to Great Britain?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the term. It's just a geographical one.

Comment: Is *North America* offensive to Canadians?

Comment: I find the term "Trade Winds" offensive. They never trade anything with me.

Comment: @TimLymington if America had once invaded Canada, and renamed it to North America, and then Canada subsequently got *most* of it back (leaving, say, Ontario under US control) then it might be a sensitive term.

Comment: @Max: You are mistaking feelings for language. If Canada sponsored a terrorist campaign in those border states that do not want to leave the US, and then renamed itself 'North America' without consulting other North Americans, that would probably cause ill-feeling. It would not, however, change the geographical status of the term *North America*.

Comment: @TimLymington there's no need to bring terrorism into it.  The question was not about geographical status, it was about whether the phrase is likely to cause offense.

Answer (score 6):

Geographers don't generally dispute it, but it can be sensitive terminology in Ireland. The [Wikipedia article on the British Isles naming dispute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Isles_naming_dispute) lists the following as alternative terms that have been suggested by various people and groups: "Britain and Ireland", "Atlantic Archipelago", "Anglo-Celtic Isles", the "British-Irish Isles", and the "Islands of the North Atlantic". However, none of these alternatives are in wide circulation, so if clarity is important, it's best to stick with British Isles in most contexts at the present.

Comment: BTW, I love your avatar: The fusion of Che Guevara with Alfred E. Neuman.  Too bad Che was not as fun-loving as Al.

Comment: Nearly all those alternatives are also less precise and no more politically correct. _Britain and Ireland_ excludes Man, Wight, Aran, etc.; _Atlantic Archipelago_ might as well be the Canaries; _Anglo-Celtic Isles_ would also include Breton isles off the coast of France; _Islands of the North Atlantic_ also includes the Faeroes and Iceland. Only _British-Irish Isles_ really works.

Comment: I've always considered the Faeroes to be part of the British Isles, geographically speaking. (Though of course they're a self-governing part of Denmark politically.) If you take a look at photos of the Faeroes, Shetlands, and Orkneys they look strikingly similar in terms of their geology, fauna, and even people.

Comment: If you want to avoid risking offence, say "the UK and Ireland".

Comment: @Max : That won't avoid offence, since the UK (a political entity) includes part of Ireland (a geographical entity). It is leaves uncertain the status of the Channel Islands and the Isle of Man.

Answer (score 1):

For a delightful and insightful video on the subject, see CGP Grey's video "The Difference between the United Kingdom, Great Britain and England Explained":

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNu8XDBSn10

Helped me out on this.  A lot.

Mr. Grey is a UK-resident Yank.

**Edited to add**: this isn't actually an Answer, it's a reference to a good resource.  @phenry's answer is an Answer, and I agree with him.